# Problema en HTTP requests POST en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Orginalmente me estaba funcionando metodo POST en android, por alguna razón ya no pero si mando el post desde POSTAMN si funciona, mi codigo en android:

```
    MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/json");
    String url = "https://data.com/registerdata";

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    JSONObject postdata = new JSONObject();

    try {
        postdata.put("IdUsuario", devideId);
        postdata.put("fecha", fecha);
        postdata.put("hora", hora);
        postdata.put("TipoCliente", tipo);
        postdata.put("NombreCliente", nombreCliente);
        postdata.put("CodigoCliente", codigo);
        postdata.put("Comentario", comentario);
        postdata.put("Latitud", lat);
        postdata.put("Longitud", longit);

    } catch(JSONException e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, postdata.toString());

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .build();


    Log.d("DEBUG","\n  DeviceId: " +devideId +  "\n Fecha: "+ fecha+"\n Hora: " + hora + "\n Tipo: " + tipo + "\n Nombre: " + nombreCliente + "\n Código: " + codigo + "\n Comentario: " + comentario + "\n Lat: " +lat + "\n Long: " + longit );

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            String mMessage = e.getMessage().toString();
            Log.e("ERROR","RESul:" +mMessage);
            //call.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            String mMessage = response.body().string();

            Log.d("DEBUG","Respuesta: " +mMessage);
        }
    });
```

En el onResponse me antes me devolvía "true", ahora me devuelve código html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
            <style>
                /* Copyright (c) 2010, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved. Code licensed under the BSD License: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/license.html */
                html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;}
                html { background: #eee; padding: 10px }
                img { border: 0; }
```

No entiendo porque desde postman si funciona, y ahora ya no en ANDROID STUDIO,
Estoy usando la version de android studio 3.5.3 y com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.1"

Comment: Se muestra algo en el LogCat al realizar la petición?

Comment: Si, en el public void onResponse, una variable mMessage me devuelve un código html, pero antres solo devolvia "true" que significa que hacia la inserción de datos.

Answer (score 0):

`onResponse()` NO puede devolver únicamente `true` (o `false`), lo que retorna es una respuesta en base a la petición.

```
 @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            String mMessage = response.body().string();

            Log.d("DEBUG","Respuesta: " +mMessage);
        }
```

**El problema es que se esta bloqueando acceso al contenido, debes requerir al administrador de la página que retorna la respuesta que permita el acceso para que puedas realizar correctamente la petición.**

Similar a el archivo [`robots.txt`](https://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) que puede bloquear el acceso a el contenido, se puede realizar mediante el tag html , de acuerdo a el error que muestras:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
```

> Puede usar una etiqueta `HTML` especial `<META>` para indicar a los robots
>   que no indexen el contenido de una página y / o que no la escaneen
>   para buscar enlaces a seguir.

Revisa también:
[Bloquear el acceso a contenido de tu sitio web](https://support.google.com/news/publisher-center/answer/9605477?hl=es)

> Para impedir que todos los robots indexen determinados artículos de tu
>   sitio web, utiliza la siguiente metaetiqueta: